# Grails domain level implementation of saveAll

Tags: csv, grails, bulkinsert

I have three domain class

```
   class Caller implements Serializable{
    String callingNumber
    String callerName
    static hasMany = [ callCallerList : CallCallerList ]
}
```

And other are

```
   class CallCallerList {
    String reason
    Caller caller 
    CallerList callerList
}
class CallerList {

    String name

}
```

> Caller

and

> CallerList

have one to many relationship with

> CallCallerList

I have huge csv file where I'm reading all the caller and put them into the callCallerList.

```
    def callerList = new CallerList(name:'test')
    def callCallerLists = []
    callerList.save(flush:true)
     groovyFile.each {
          ArrayList<String> line = it.split(',').toList()
          def caller = new Caller(callingNumber:line.get(0),callerName:line.get(1))
//I want to save the object latter when I run the saveAll function for this domain class. 
def callCallerList = new CallCallerList(caller:caller,callerList:callerList,reason:line.get(2))
    callCallerLists.add(callCallerList)
// this gives me the error that caller is unsaved object. 
}
CallCallerList.saveAll(callCallerLists)
```

I do not want to save the caller because my process gets slow if millions of records in the file and if some error occurs while creating the bulk callCallerList then all callers are saved but not in any callerList. 
I want to do this

```
Caller.saveAll(callers)
CallCallerList(callCallerLists)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and solve the above problem.

```
def callerList = new CallerList(name:'test')
    def callCallerLists = []
    def callers = []
    callerList.save(flush:true)
     groovyFile.each {
          ArrayList<String> line = it.split(',').toList()
          def caller = new Caller(callingNumber:line.get(0),callerName:line.get(1))
//I want to save the object latter when I run the saveAll function for this domain class. 
def callCallerList = new CallCallerList(callerList:callerList,reason:line.get(2))
     callers.add(caller)
    callCallerLists.add(callCallerList)
// this gives me the error that caller is unsaved object. 
}
Caller.saveAll(callers)
for(int i =0;i< callCallerLists?.size();i++){
                    callCallerLists?.get(i)?.caller = callers?.get(i)
                }
CallCallerList.saveAll(callCallerLists)
```